# How do I apply firefox source code extensions and settings to distributed mode?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools

I am working on the Firefox source code and I want to make sure that when I distribute the compiled version, the user profile that opens in the browser is the same as the one found in a specific location in the source code(obj-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\tmp\profile-default) . How can I make sure that the user profile that opens in the distributed Firefox contains the same extensions and settings as the user profile stored in the source code

Additional details: I am on windows 10

All extensions and settings in the ./mach run mode are the same as in the distributed version ./mach package